# Update mergeinfo data after bad merge

Tags: svn, merge, branch, mergeinfo

Have a question for all SVN gurus here!

I have a feature branch, based of trunk. I did a merge to sync work done in trunk in the branch and committed all changes **except mergeinfo prop on branch root**. So now, when i try to do another sync merge, it tries to reapply all the changes already applied in the previous merge.

Is there an easy way of recording this information in the mergeinfo property so it behaves correctly? I know exactly the changes that were applied in the bad merge. Essentially it is the output of:

```
svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible ^/trunk@12345
```

where 12345 is the revision number from the merge.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform previous merge again with option --record-only and commit. This restore correct merge info, so 'another sync merge' will be OK.